# Store variable VALUES to array from a loop

Tags: php

This code adds four instances of `${"v$i"}` to my array, which when called just shows "duck" four times.  Because of course `$i` at this point is 4.  What I want to do is add the variable VALUES to my array, rather than the variable name.  This way the first iteration would find variable `v1`, and add the value of "cat" to my array.  And so on.  How do I do this?

```
   <?php 

    v1="cat"; 
    v2="dog"; 
    v3="turtle"; 
    v4="duck"; 
    $animals = array(); 

    for ($i=1; $i<5; $i++) { 
      $animals[]=$ {"v$i"}; 
    } 

    print_r ($animals); 

    ?>
```

Comment: working fine here http://ideone.com/WrgrGr . you didn't give `$` before variable name . That's just a typo right ?

Comment: Yes typo, thanks.  Interesting that this code works.  I need to figure out why this implementation isn't working in my specific code...

Comment: Ahh, it was a horribly dumb mistake.  I wasn't using $i in my actual code.  Thanks for confirming the code works so I could find that!